# Query to return only records that are within 60 seconds of being posted

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query here that I use to find messages between users:

```
SELECT *
FROM msgs
WHERE
    (recipientid = '{$_SESSION['rider_id']}' AND authorid = '{$riderid}') 
    OR
    (authorid = '{$_SESSION['rider_id']}' AND recipientid = '{$riderid}')
ORDER BY datesent DESC
```

Now I have an AJAX call that will fire every 30 seconds once on the actual page to dynamically post new messages and I want it to grab any messages that have been posted that are within 30 seconds of being posted. And I cannot get it to work. I tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM msgs
WHERE
     (recipientid = '{$_SESSION['rider_id']}' AND authorid = '{$authorrider['id']}')
     OR
     (authorid = '{$_SESSION['rider_id']}' AND recipientid = '{$authorrider['id']}')
     AND
     (datesent >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 30 SECOND))
```

But it still returns *all* the messages. Not ones just within the last 30 seconds.

I also need to set a status to 1 once it has been pulled, so if someone makes two replies within the 30 seconds it won't be pulled and .prepended () twice.

So once I can get the records I need, I will have to run a SET query to set the status. My MySQL isn't really up to polish to know how to accomplish this.

Another way I just thought of is setting status to 1 whenever it is retrieved. Then my AJAX query can just pull the records that status = 0.

Comment: Actually i like the sound of that better, if i can just adjust that first query to test the status = 0 aswell, that would get me out of trouble. Can anyone help me on that?

Comment: Old question and unrelated, but for anyone else coming across this question who codes the same way: don't. Use statements, not only is it a lot cleaner, but a lot safer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is the lack of parentheses on the `where` clause.  Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM msgs
WHERE ((recipientid = '{$_SESSION['rider_id']}' AND authorid = '{$authorrider['id']}') OR 
       (authorid = '{$_SESSION['rider_id']}' AND recipientid = '{$authorrider['id']}')
      ) AND 
      (datesent >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 30 SECOND));
```

Comment: Any ideas on adjusting that first query to only return records that have a status of "1"? This might work out being more stable for what im doing?

Comment: @22Ryann . . . You would add `AND status = 1` as an additional condition in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine your ID criteria in parentheses. As it is, if your `recipientid` and `authorid` criteria match, anything after the `OR` (including the date) will never be checked.

So:

```sql
SELECT * FROM msgs WHERE 
 ((recipientid = '{$_SESSION['rider_id']}' AND authorid = '{$authorrider['id']}') OR
  (authorid = '{$_SESSION['rider_id']}' AND recipientid = '{$authorrider['id']}')) AND
 (datesent >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 30 SECOND))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM msgs WHERE (recipientid = '{$_SESSION['rider_id']}' AND authorid = '{$authorrider['id']}') OR (authorid = '{$_SESSION['rider_id']}' AND recipientid = '{$authorrider['id']}') AND (DATE_DIFF(datesent,NOW()) > 30))
```

Try that

Comment: DATEDIFF* ? this still retrieves all, after an extra parenthesis on the very end?

Answer (score 0):

I try to remove any thinking a db has to do and make the client do the work. For this, I would send a timestamp minus 30 seconds in the ajax query, instead of making the DB figure it out.

If this doesn't make sense I'd like to hear why.